# Bot Framework Bot with AWS EC2 endpoint displays 500 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, botframework

I have developed a bot using bot frame work  . I have tested it locally using emulator and it was working fine. I have published it to a folder for iis website however the bot is not replying back.

Note the bot is already registered and i have set up the bot app id and password in web config. The end point was set to https://serverip/api/messages but when i access it from within the server it is not accessible and i get internl error 500.

Also i have installed an ssl certificate on my website.

Can someone pls guide me on how to fix this error message? I dont know what else need to be done or how to troubleshoot this issue. Ive gone through microsoft documentation but i found nothing solves my issue.

Right now Im not sure if this could be an AWS server issue?

Comment: What do you see when you navigate to https://serverip/api/messages in a browser?

Comment: It shows internal error 500: There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: Can anyone pls help me with this issue.. I'm still struggling.

Comment: It seems the deployment of the bot has not been done successfully.  This does not have anything to do with the bot specifically, but with deployment.  You should see "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'." when navigating to serverip/api/messages

Comment: Can you please explain further?

Comment: And what is the solution for this problem? On azure website it is working fine.

Comment: Anyone else had same issue?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the bot locally?